# How to retrieve the value of a variable modified in the onItemSelected function with Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, case, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I need to retrieve the value of a variable modified in the `onItemSelected` function using a when.
Here is what I've done :

```
    (...)

    private var i: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        (...)

        categorySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                category = categories[position]

                when (category) {
                    "Décès" -> i = 1
                    "Habitat" -> i = 2
                }
            }
        }

        binding.tvtest.text = i.toString()

        val acteSpinner: Spinner = binding.acteCreatingSpinnerActes
        when (i) {
            1 -> {
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, actes[actes.indexOf(deces)])
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                acteSpinner.adapter = adapter
                acte = acteSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
            }
            2 -> {
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, actes[actes.indexOf(habitat)])
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                acteSpinner.adapter = adapter
                acte = acteSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to retrieve the value of variable I in a layout and I got `i = 0`.
I want to get the value obtained in the `onItemSelected` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    categorySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : ItemSelected{
                    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?,   view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            category = categories[position]

            when (category) {
                "Décès" ->  getItemSelected(1)
                "Habitat" ->  getItemSelected(2)
            }}}
}

private fun setDataSpinner(i: Int,actes: Actes){
    binding.tvtest.text = i.toString()
    val acteSpinner: Spinner = binding.acteCreatingSpinnerActes

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item, actes)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    acteSpinner.adapter = adapter
    acte = acteSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
}

private fun getItemSelected(item: Int){
    when(item){
        1 -> { setDataSpinner(item,actes[actes.indexOf(deces)]) }
        2 -> { setDataSpinner(item,actes[actes.indexOf(habitat)]) }
    }
}


interface ItemSelected: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long)
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Should not use hard-string in code: "Décès", "Habitat"
2. No need i variable. Just using position:

```
when (position) {
        0 -> {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, actes[actes.indexOf(deces)])
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            acteSpinner.adapter = adapter
            acte = acteSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
        }
        1 -> {
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, actes[actes.indexOf(habitat)])
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            acteSpinner.adapter = adapter
            acte = acteSpinner.selectedItem.toString()
        } }
```

Comment: the problem here is that ArrayAdapter is not permitted in onItemSelected method

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with changing a class member inside the callback, but your code as-written doesn't work because the callback doesn't run immediately - it runs later when the user clicks on an item.

It appears you want the adapter for `acteSpinner` to change between two different sets of data when you select something in `categorySpinner`. You can do that by modifying the data in the adapter directly. Here's an example of how you could do that.

```kotlin
// You could make adapter a class member, but it is not necessary
// for this example
//private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    
    val binding = ...
    
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    acteSpinner.adapter = adapter
    
    // Initially set the adapter to show list one
    adapter.addAll(firstList)
    binding.tvtest.text = "List One"
    
    categorySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            category = categories[position]
            // POINT B - Inside the callback. This code does not
            // run immediately, it runs later when an 
            // item is selected

            when (category) {
                "Décès" -> {
                    adapter.clear()
                    adapter.addAll(decesArray)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    binding.tvtest.text = "Décès"
                    println("TEST: added deces ${decesArray.contentToString()}")
                }
                "Habitat" -> {
                    adapter.clear()
                    adapter.addAll(habitatArray)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    binding.tvtest.text = "Habitat"
                    println("TEST: added habitat ${habitatArray.contentToString()}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // POINT A - Outside the callback
    //...
}
```

Note the "Point A" and "Point B" comments - in this code "Point A" will run first, even though "Point B" is on an earlier line. If you try to do something at "Point A" using a variable you modified at "Point B" it will not work.

Comment: It works i can now retrieve the the good list but i don't see the list elements in the spinner. i recieve '[Ljava.lang.String;@.....'

Comment: Add an edit to your question that shows your updated code. It sounds like either your array of strings has bad values or you called `adapter.add(arr.toString())` instead of `adapter.addAll(arr)`. You can check the values of the array itself with `println("TEST: my array = ${arr.contentToString()}")` and filtering for "TEST:" in the logcat

Comment: `when (category) {
                    "Décès" -> {
                        adapter.clear()
                        adapter.addAll(deces)
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        binding.tvtest.text = "Liste un"
                    }
                    "Habitat" -> {
                        adapter.clear()
                        adapter.addAll(habitat)
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        binding.tvtest.text = "Liste deux"
                    }}`

Comment: What is `deces`, is it an array of strings, or an array of arrays? Print it out and see. In your original code the arrays you added were `actes[actes.indexOf(deces)]` and `actes[actes.indexOf(habitat)]`, so if those were correct you would need to use something like `adapter.addAll(actes[actes.indexOf(deces)])`

Comment: I added some example print statements to the code showing how you could print out the list of strings you are adding to the adapter to make sure they are what you expect.

Comment: `deces` is an array of Strings and `actes` is un array of arrays of Strings which contents `deces` and `habitat`, it means `actes[actes.indexOf(deces)] = deces`. in the layout i recieve the array value instead of the array elements

Comment: Please post the updated code *in the question, not as a comment*, including how you create the adapter and what you see from printing out the array contents to the log, or ask a new question if the problem is a new problem.